# Critical section initialization when creating thread-safe singleton (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, critical-section

I'm trying to do the same thing as suggested in this solution:

[How can I create a thread-safe singleton pattern in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164496/how-can-i-create-a-thread-safe-singleton-pattern-in-windows/164640#164640)

But, where should the critical section be initialized and uninitialized?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the critical section into a class (use a ready one or craft your own) and declare a global variable of that class - then the critical section will be initialized during the program startup and deinitialized on program exit. Since startup and exit are done on one thread it will work reliably.

Comment: Understood what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use pthread_once() and you can initialize the critical section before you use it for the first time. Windows has [InitOnceExecuteOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683493(VS.85).aspx) function.

Comment: With boost (instead of pthread_once() ), you can use a solution like I did in this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955921/thread-safe-initialization-of-function-local-static-const-objects/2956314#2956314

Comment: If you have pthread, you don't need windows critical sections