# What is an in-place constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, placement-new, in-place

What is an in-place constructor in C++?

e.g. `Datatype *x = new(y) Datatype();`

Comment: This is also called _placement new_ and you might have better chances finding information for that name.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is called the placement new operator.  It allows you to supply the memory the data will be allocated in without having the `new` operator allocate it. For example:

```
Foo * f = new Foo();
```

The above will allocate memory for you.

```
void * fm = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
Foo *f = new (fm) Foo();
```

The above will use the memory allocated by the call to `malloc`.  `new` will not allocate any more.  You are not, however, limited to classes.  You can use a placement new operator for any type you would allocate with a call to `new`.

A 'gotcha' for placement new is that you **should not** release the memory allocated by a call to the placement new operator using the `delete` keyword.  You will destroy the object by calling the destructor directly.

```
f->~Foo();
```

After the destructor is manually called, the memory can then be freed as expected.

```
free(fm);
```

Comment: Yep. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697892/what-is-return-type-of-new-in-c/2697929#2697929) for the difference between a _new expression_ and actual memory allocation.

Comment: "`new` will not allocate any more." - for the object as a fixed-sized thing - sure but of course it will allocate dynamic memory if the object requires it - strings, framebuffers, databases, whatever.

Comment: Is the destructor allowed to use free() to deallocate the memory allocated to the object through malloc? I am assuming the answer is yes. However, Is there a catch to this?

Comment: @thegreatcoder Yes. that is what should happen. I will update the answer.

Comment: Make sure to include header `<new>`!

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that your code constructs an object in the space pointed to by `y`.  The long answer is best covered by the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.14).

Answer (score 4):

This is more commonly known as 'placement new' and is discussed pretty well by the C++ FAQ (in the 'Destructors' area):

- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10

It allows you to construct objects in raw memory, which can be useful in certain specialized situations, such as when you might want to allocate an array for a large number of possible objects, but want to construct then as needed because you often might not need anywhere near the maximum, or because you want or need to use a custom memory allocator.

Answer (score 2):

I'm rusty on this one but it allows you to write the object to a memory block you have already allocated.  It also needs a reciprocal delete statement to clear it from memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a memory pool, then you need to use the in place constructor to initialize your object as they are allocated from the pool.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way to call a constructor without allocating memory. Your `y` has to be a pointer poniting to enough memory for a new Datatype object. Also, don't call `delete`, call `~DataType()`.