# Create array/vector of items with different constructor arguments per item

Tags: c++

I want to create an array/vector (indifferent to which one) of class instances. I have the following constraints:

1. Each instance is constructed with a different argument (e.g., `Item(0)`, `Item(1)`, `Item(2)`, ...).
2. The `Item` class has both its copy and move constructors deleted.

Constraint #2 above seems to rule out using an `std::vector` since the vector would need to either copy or move the enqueued instances when it resizes its backing store.

This leaves me with an array. For both a C-style array and `std::array`, there does not seem to be any way to specify custom constructors for items in the array, so I can't custom construct items in-place in array indices. The only other option is to create an array of pointers and do `array[0] = new Object(0);`, `array[1] = new Object(1);`, `array[2] = new Object(2);`, but this is messy since it allocates memory on the heap rather than just the stack and requires me to explicitly free memory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just to clarify: what you want is to pass the index of the object in the array to its constructor?

Comment: do you need to resize the container after its creation?

Comment: @Kein That happens to be true, but I would also want to know how to do this when that is not the case.

Comment: @bolov No, I know the size upfront.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
struct Item
{
    Item(int);
    Item(const Item&) = delete;
    Item(Item&&) = delete;
};
```

You have some options:

## smart pointers

You can use smart pointers, in this case `std::unique_ptr`:

```
auto test()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> v;

    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item>(1));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item>(2));
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item>(3));
}
```

## `std::array`

If you do not need to resize or move the container you can use `std::array` (since C++17):

```
auto test2()
{
    std::array<Item, 3> arr{1, 2, 3};
}
```

This works since C++17 because of the new temporary materialization rules.

Comment: Wow, using temporary materialization to do this looks great! For my own knowledge, can we do this with a C array?

Comment: Additionally, is there a way to do this when I don't know the argument values (1, 2, 3 above) at compile time?

Comment: @JackHumphries: `auto test3(int a, int b, int c)
{
    std::array<Item, 3> arr{a, b, c};
}` is fine.

Comment: It also looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763846/what-is-an-in-place-constructor-in-c could be useful here.