# In C++ how to declare a global, statically allocated variable with a virtual base type?

Tags: c++, memory

[Edit: sorry, mixed up base & subclass initially]

Given

```
class Car : public Vehicle {...}
```

I would like to declare a global variable of type Vehicle (or &Vehicle if need be), initialized as a Car instance... something like

```
Vehicle &myCar = Car(red);
```

... except that the above doesn't compile.
What matters to me is that the instance is allocated in exactly the same way as if I had used (this is for AVR programming)

```
 Car myCar(red);
```

I have searched but I just can't figure out the syntax for this??

Thanks!

Comment: You have your concepts backwards. `Car` is a type of `Vehicle`, not the other way around. You cannot instantiate the base class then assign it to the derived class.

Comment: Use pointer type. You cannot initialize an incomplete type but only allocate

Comment: What does "initialized as a Vehicle instance" mean?

Comment: Car &myCar = Vehicle(red); is totally incorrect. What you can do is: static Car* _myCar = nullptr;   static Vehicle* getCar() { if(nullptr == _myCar;) _myCar = new Car(red); return _myCar;  }; And it is also needs to be synchronized to be [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164496/how-can-i-create-a-thread-safe-singleton-pattern-in-windows).

Comment: Looks like this is XY problem and you do not understand what you want/need to do

Comment: No you do not, problem is Vehicle is not a Car so your assignment is bogus. And why you need such thing is completely unclear and shows you do not understand how things work.

Comment: if you want this `Car &myCar = Vehicle(red);` then you are definitely on the wrong track. Please try to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @franck102 Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188894/why-doesnt-polymorphism-work-without-pointers-references)

Comment: what is the "virtual base class" in your title? in the question there is none....

Comment: *"... except that the above doesn't compile."*. Usually the compiler issues a diagnostic message that will explain why the program is ill-formed. Also, see [mcve].

Comment: @all - thanks, pls see the edited version. Vehicle is the virtual base class, and the variable type I want to use later.

Comment: @franck102 *". Vehicle is the virtual base class"* In the example code it appears to be a non-virtual base class.

Comment: In your code `Vehicle` is not a virtual base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have an explicit variable of the derived type:

```
Vehicle &&myCar = Car(red);
```

The rvalue reference will extend the temporary's lifetime as needed. The advantage over [melpomene's lambda solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323438/in-c-how-to-declare-a-global-statically-allocated-variable-with-a-virtual-bas/49323901#comment85648974_49323715) is that that `Car` keeps its automatic lifetime instead of becoming static.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
Car myActualCar(red);
Vehicle &myCar = myActualCar;
```

First create a `Car`, then provide a `Vehicle` reference bound to the car.

If you don't want to expose `myActualCar` to the rest of the file, you can use a lambda function to hide it (this is analoguous to the IIFE technique in JavaScript):

```
Vehicle &myCar = []() -> Car & { static Car myActualCar; return myActualCar; }();
```

This technique requires C++11.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to post exactly that; so there is no way to avoid exposing the myActualCar variable to the rest of the program?

Comment: There is a way in @SergeyA's (deleted) answer. I've voted to undelete it, but here it is again: `Vehicle &myCar = []() { static Car myActualCar(red); return myActualCar; }();`

Comment: Wow :) I am accepting your answer.
I don't know enough about C++ compilers and AVR C++ compilers to be 100% that the above will result in the exact same memory allocations on the target processor, so I will live with the dummy "actual" variable. Thanks!