# Thread-safe singleton in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, thread-safety

I know the following is a thread-safe way to implement a singleton in C++11:

```
Foo* getInst()
{
    static Foo* inst = new Foo(...);
    return inst;
}
```

I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19907903/506624) that the following is also thread-safe:

```
Foo& getInst()
{
    static Foo inst(...);
    return inst;
}
```

Is it really thread-safe?
Isn't it a problem that the instance of Foo <strike>will be allocated in a single stack frame</strike> will not be allocated on the heap?

If it is thread-safe, is there a strong reason to prefer one to the other?

Comment: *Both* variables are static, implying the same lifetime semantics, so if the second one wasn't safe then the first one wouldn't be either.

Comment: Keep in mind that static initialization is thread-safe in c++11, previous versions of the standard do not make this guarantee. Additionaly, in MSVC2012 and 2013 the static initialization contains bugs and is actually not thread safe. For cross-platform code i would advice to avoid the usage of the so called magic statics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Static variables are *NOT* allocated on the stack. In the first variant you have a static pointer (a global variable) initialized with a memory obtained from the heap, while in the second one you have whole static object.

Both versions use internal compiler guards (namely `__cxa_guard_acquire()` and `__cxa_guard_release()`, which are functionally equivalent to `mutex::lock()` and `mutex::unlock()`) to ensure serialized access to a special variable that tells whether or not your global instances are already initialized or not.

Your code:

```
Foo& getInst()
{
    static Foo inst(...);
    return inst;
}
```

will actually look like that after the compilation:

```
Foo& getInst()
{
    static Foo inst; // uninitialized - zero
    static guard instGuard; // zero

    if (is_initialized(instGuard) == false)
    {
        __cxa_guard_acquire(instGuard);
        // do the initialization here - calls Foo constructor
        set_initialized(instGuard);
        __cxa_guard_release(instGuard);
    }

    return inst;
}
```

So both of your exampes are thread safe.

Comment: @Kaveh - exactly as safe as your first version. I'll edit the answer in a second to be more precise.

Comment: I checked the standard. Static members work as you wrote by default (as long as they are not declared `thread_local` there will be a single instance for all threads).

Answer (score 4):

`inst` in your example won't be allocated on stack. It will be allocated somewhere in `.data` or `.bss` section. Otherwise this static variable couldn't live all the time program executes, and so it couldn't have the same value, which was before, each time you enter this function.