# c++ singleton, strange error

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm implementing a thread-safe singleton. But this aspect (singleton & thread-safe) is not part of my question.

Compare the two codes. Code 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class DataLocation {
private:
  DataLocation(std::string) {
  }
public:
  DataLocation& getInstance() {
    std::string s = " ";
    static DataLocation instance(s);
    return instance;
  }
};
int main() {
}
```

and code 2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class DataLocation {
private:
  DataLocation() {
  }
public:
  DataLocation& getInstance() {
    static DataLocation instance();    
    return instance;
  }
};
int main() {
}
```

Code 1 compiles fine. Code 2 gives the following error:

```
15_singleton.cpp: In member function ‘DataLocation& DataLocation::getInstance()’:
15_singleton.cpp:15:34: error: cannot declare static function inside another function
     static DataLocation instance();    
                                  ^
15_singleton.cpp:16:12: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘DataLocation&’ from an rvalue of type ‘DataLocation (*)()’
     return instance;
            ^
```

From my point of view the only difference is that the private constructor has one, respectively zero parameters.

How can I help the compiler to understand that I'm not defining anything new, but I'm just calling the constructor? The compiler is able to understand it, when there is one parameter.

Comment: Or use curly braces.

Comment: About your threadsafe part, read up on C++ guarantees for initialization time and order of statics.

Comment: @MikeMB: what do you mean with _use curly braces_?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That is _not_ the most vexing parse. Please do not spread misconceptions!!

Comment: @LiPo MikeMB means you could use `static DataLocation instance{};` Since C++11, this is possible. One of the reasons why it was introduced is the problem you had here; with {} there is no ambiguity anymore.

Comment: @MikeMB: ok, the solution with curly brackets is simply the nicest.

Comment: @deviantfan: thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the brackets

```
static DataLocation instance;
```

To create the instance with the default constructor.

Alternatively, use the braced form of initialisation.

```
static DataLocation instance {};
```

Comment: @LiPo This is perfectly "logical"; MVP is a well defined language rule.

Comment: well defined is not necessarily logical. one parameter: foo(param), no parameter foo(). that is for me logical. bu we are all different and we have different logics

Answer (score 2):

```
static DataLocation instance = DataLocation();
```

or

```
static DataLocation instance;
```

And you would probably want to declare `DataLocation& getInstance();` as a `static` method.

Comment: Not sure why you would want the first version. Especially as, for a singleton, you usually disable the copy constructor so the first version should not compile.

Answer (score 2):

You are using brackets `()` while declaring

```
static DataLocation instance();
```

which you intent to create as an object. But is, simply a function declaration. And you cannot create a `static` function inside some other non-`static` function. That is what your error refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Method `getInstance()` should be declared as a static.

Comment: I would also define it static, but I used this [model](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19907903), and the model got +33...and I'm a beginner

Comment: @Niall: There is no ambiguity. Surprise for some? Sure. But by definition there is no ambiguity. BTW, the most vexing parse relates to `A a(B());`. It's caused by the same language rules as a novice's surprise after using the wrong declarator syntax.

Comment: @LiPo: I did't downvote, but while Radek is right, it doesn't answer the question.