# How to implement global string to constructor map in C++?

Tags: c++, serialization

I have an interface for file parser. This parser can be configured, then saved to the file. New parsers for new file types can be added using `.dll` plugins.

```
class FileParserInterface {
public:
    QString toString() const = 0;
    QString constructorName() const {return "FileParserInterface";}
    SomeDataStruct getData() = 0;
}
```

Therefore I need some way to save those instances by name (can be name of the constructor). I would then have some method to get instance by string, eg:

```
static std::shared_ptr<FileParserInterface> fileParserFromString(const QString& name, const QString& parameters);
```

I have no idea how to thread-safely implement this. I am using boost and Qt libraries. I prefer to use stdlib and Qt when possible.

Comment: Sounds like a `Factory` pattern, so maybe refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576022/efficient-thread-safe-singleton-in-c?

Comment: @Mine The problem is I need to allow items to be added to the global map variable. So it must be writable but still thread-safe. The post you mentioned covers single (presumably read-only) class instance.

Comment: @TomášZato you have to mutex out the factory just like you would have to do that with any other modifiable shared resource.

Comment: @n.m. I was hoping for some magic to do it for me. Mutexing stuff is tedious and produces ugly code, even in C++

Comment: @TomášZato you just encapsulate it in the methods of the factory.

Comment: Look at Qt. It has a lot of similar examples: item editors ([1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemeditorfactory.html#createEditor) [2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemeditorfactory.html#registerEditor)), SQL drivers plugins ([1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#registerSqlDriver) [2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldriverplugin.html) [3](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-write-your-own-database-driver)), other plugins ([1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html)).