# Is this Singleton Implementation Thread-Safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, singleton, atomic

I've read the question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576022/efficient-thread-safe-singleton-in-c), and learned that a true thread-safe singleton can be implemented with correctly placed memory barrier, which is stated [here](https://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) in chapter 6. I've come up with my own version of singleton implementation, by reviewing the code I've seen no memory ordering problem so far, but it differs a lot from a typical DCLP approach. Do you think this is a reliable implementation?

```
static std::atomic<T*> _instance;
...
Singleton* get_instance() {
    ins = _instance.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (ins == nullptr) {
        T* temp = nullptr;
        {            
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(_lock);
            temp = new(std::nothrow) T;
        }

        if(!_instance.compare_exchange_strong(nullptr, temp, std::memory_order_release)) {
            delete temp;
        }
    }
    return _instance.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
}
```

Comment: This looks unsafe for me when the constructor of `T` is not thread-safe.

Comment: Any specific reason why `_instance` can't simply be a static member of this function, and simply letting the compiler worry about the whole thing being thread-safe?

Comment: Edit: Added a lock around new T as @MikeCAT pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to beat a simple

```
class Singleton { ... };

Singleton* get_instance()
{
    static Singleton instance; // guaranteed to be thread safe in C++11
    return &instance;
}
```

Any access to the pointer after it has been returned is still not thread safe, but neither is access in your implementation.

Comment: I think this is the best solution under C++11 standard.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think this is a reliable implementation?

That depends on class `T`. Some classes must be singleton because there can be only one instance at any given moment, physically. I.e. an attempt to create a second instance would certainly fail, for example due to both of them requiring exclusive access to some unique external resource.

Proposed implementation *does* allow for concurrent construction of two instances of `T`, which may lead to wonderful race-induced bugs.

Edit:
Even with the lock protecting `new T`, this solution still does not guarantee that `T` is constructed only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation should only be used as an educational tool (use `static` in real software).
It has issues; multiple objects can be created (and all but one are deleted again), but at least it is thread-safe.

The first `load` can even be `mo_relaxed` since synchronization with `compare_exchange(release)` is covered by the `load(mo_acquire)` return statement.

In a DCLP implemention you would use a mutex to avoid creation of multiple objects and to block threads that are waiting for the creator to finish.
Since your implementation already allows multiple objects, the `mutex` is not necessary from a correctness point of view (unless indeed the constructor is not thread safe).

If multiple threads create object `T`, the one that stores the pointer to `_instance`, releases the object (say thread N),
while the others (say N+1) have to perform a `load` again; this second `load(mo_acquire)` in N+1 can never return `nullptr`.
The `compare_exchange` in thread N+1 failed because it came later in the modification order than the first execution in thread N,
which means that the `compare_exchange` (in N) also precedes the second load (in N+1) in the modification order and therefore it is guaranteed to return the object pointer to a synchronized object