# Can in this way be declared a global object class?

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point, global-object

I do not know why but this code works, what does this record `}r;` and how it works ? can in this way be declared a global object class ?

```
#include <iostream>

class А
{
    public:
        А()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello World";
        }
}r;

int main()
{

}
```

Comment: More fittingly simply a global *object* of type `A`.

Comment: pls read here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798608/c-declare-a-global-class-and-access-it-from-other-classes

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That declares a global variable named `r` that is of type `A`.

It's the same as

```
class A { ... };

A r;

int main() { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

> can in this way be declared a global object class ?

Um, yeah! Basically, `r` there is a global variable of type `А`. C++ has inherited from C a certain syntax that enables you to declare variables after a class/struct definition. You can often see from C something like

```
struct vertex {
   float x, y;
} my_vertex; // Declares a variable of type vertex
```

In C++, a `struct` is the same as `class` with the exception of the default access specifier.

You might have wondered what the semicolon is for after class definitions. So basically a class defined as

```
class my_class {};
```

with the braces immediately proceeded by a semicolon declares no variables.

You can also declare more than one variables by delimiting them with the comma operator.

```
class my_class {} x, y, z;
```

Answer (score 0):

It Create one instance of `class A` with name `r`. It's pretty much the same as doint `int r;` Which would make a global int on that position.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps you for a better understanding.

[C++: Declare a global class and access it from other classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798608/c-declare-a-global-class-and-access-it-from-other-classes)

br