# Specify construction/destruction order of static locals in different accessors

Tags: c++, gcc, initialization, clang

I'm experiencing a crash in `cxa_finalize` running a program (this is a program, and not a library within):

```
$ ./ac-test.exe 
Assertion failed: AcLock.cpp(54): AcLock
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called without an active exception
Abort trap: 6
```

The assertion/crash is due to the interaction between an object and a logger. The logger is destructed before the object, but the object uses the logger. So the mutex being acquired that pops the assert or crash has already been destroyed (hence the reason `pthread_mutex_lock` fails when locking the logger).

I've read the GCC manual on [Specifying Attributes of Variables](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) and [Declaring Attributes of Functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html), but I'm obviously missing something.

I placed the object and logger in a common header within accessors and tried to specify a construction order:

```
// AcGlobals.h
static AcLogger& GetLogger() {

    static AcLogger logger __attribute__(init_priority(50));
    return logger;
}
static AcSocketList& GetAcceptSockets() {

    static AcSocketList sockets __attribute__(init_priority(100));
    return sockets;
}
```

That resulted in a bunch of errors:

```
./AcGlobals.h:24:46: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    static AcLogger logger __attribute__((init_priori...

./AcGlobals.h:24:47: warning: declaration does not declare anything
      [-Wmissing-declarations]
    static AcLogger logger __attribute__((init_priori...
```

I also tried placing the attribute on the function rather than the variable:

```
// AcGlobals.h
static AcLogger& GetLogger() __attribute__(init_priority(50)) {

    static AcLogger logger;
    return logger;
}
static AcSocketList& GetAcceptSockets() __attribute__(init_priority(100)) {

    static AcSocketList sockets;
    return sockets;
}
```

This resulted in more problems:

```
./AcGlobals.h:22:53: warning: GCC does not allow init_priority attribute in this
      position on a function definition [-Wgcc-compat]
static AcLogger& GetLogger() __attribute__((init_priority(50))) {
                                              ^
./AcGlobals.h:22:53: error: can only use 'init_priority' attribute on file-scope
      definitions of objects of class type
```

I also tried `__attribute__((constructor(50)))` instead of `init_priority` with no joy.

*Note*: I'm working on an Apple machine. Apple has a 'feature' where constructor priority only applies to adorned functions and variables within the same file. So these cannot be spread out across translation units.

How, precisely, do I specify the order of construction and destruction of local static objects?

Comment: Are you using GCC or Clang?

Comment: I use both, but above is from Clang 3.3 built from sources. (I also use ICC and VS in an attempt to remove all implementation defined and undefined behavior).

Comment: The sane solution would be to just *get fewer globals*. Since you can't easily control the construction (and destruction) order of globals, then rather than jumping through endless hoops to try to talk the compiler into doing that in the order you want, just don't create globals that depend on other globals.

Comment: @jalf If you look at the code... His problem isn't order of initialization; he's used the Meyers singleton idiom to solve this.  It's order of destruction (since his error is in `cxa_finalize`, which it the g++ function for calling destructors at program end).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical problem when using the Meyers singleton
(which is basically what you're doing).  The solution is to
*not* destruct the singleton; instead of a static local 
variable, you should use dynamic allocation without a delete:

```
static  AcLogger& GetLogger()
{
    static AcLogger* logger = new AcLogger;
    return *logger;
}
```

Note that in this case, you will have to ensure that each use of
the logger flushes (but this is usually the case anyway);
otherwise, you may end up with unflushed data.

With regards to your attempt to use an extended feature of your
compiler: I'm not too familiar with it, but I don't see how you
can use something called `init_priority` on a local variable.
The construction (and destruction) time of local static
variables is defined by the language (and in this case, the
destruction time is *not* what you want).  If you want to use
this non-standard extension, you'll probably have to make the
instance variable a static class member, or maybe even a global
(in which case, you can't make the constructor private).

Comment: @Nim Yes.  I'll add it.

Comment: Thanks James. That's interesting - prefer the memory leak over the crash ;) It could be the lesser of the evils. How can I ensure the logger flushes when the program closes? I was relying on the `dtor` for the final flush.

Comment: @noloader It's not really a memory leak.  As for the flush...  I usually access the logger object through a locally designed class, which ensures the flush; you typically want to flush after each record in a log, so you have something up to date in case your code crashes.  Otherwise, it's up to you ensure that any log requests in a destructor are flushed in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dependency is non-cyclical, you can just leverage the standard behavior of initialization in the order of code flow entry into the function and destruction in reverse order of initialization.

In other words, have a call to GetLogger() to initialize the logger and then GetAcceptSockets() to initialize the list. This will result in the socket list getting destructed first (while the logger still exists) and then the logger getting destructed last.

Comment: Thanks Corbin. "non-cyclical" - yes, there are no circular dependencies. I also tired the "call GetLogger first in `main`" trick. It did not work.

Comment: @noloader Hmm, clang is usually extremely standard conforming. I wonder if its optimizer is getting overzealous and getting rid of the call. If you compile with optimizations disabled, does it destruct in the proper order?

Comment: The above is debug config with `-DDEBUG=1`, `-O0`, `-g3`, `-ggdb`. In a release config, the tail of the log gets trampled. And yeah, Clang is great (especially 3.3 with its sanitizers).

Comment: @noloader are you certain that the program functions correctly other than the destruction order? Have you tried adding some simple `std::cout` style debugging to see what order they're destructing in?

Comment: yes, I'm fairly certain. The project is young and I'm slowly adding functionality. So there's very few moving parts at the moment: about 6 constructors, logging the function calls, and a call to OpenSSL's various init functions (I have not yet created a socket). But I did find a workaround: (1) use `constructor` attribute with an init priority, (2) add a `cpp` file, (3) declare in the `h` file with `constructor` attribute, and (4) implement in the `cpp` file.