# Access violation inserting element into global map

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, win64

I'm returning to a C++ application that used to work correctly after about 4 years. My first task was to update it from Windows XP/.NET Framework 3.5/Win32/VS2008 to Windows 7/.NET Framework 4.5/Win64/VS2012.

The program has a global map declaration that now receives an access violation the first time it attempt to insert an element whereas it previously ran correctly. I've looked at all of the relevant references here but can't find a solution so I'd appreciate some help. The code looks like this:

**Attributes.h**:

```
static void LoadAttributes(void);
```

**Attributes.cpp**:

```
#include "sys\types.h"
#include <map>

static map<string,int> AttributeTable;

void LoadAttributes(void)
{
   AttributeTable.insert(pair<string,int>("attribute1",1));
   AttributeTable.insert(pair<string,int>("attribute2",2));
   ...
}
```

As soon as it executes the first insert, it give an access violation. It looks like an initialization problem since intellisense shows an address for the map but undefined `_Right` and `_Left` pointers: `(_Right=?????, _Left=?????)`.

A map declared locally within the method has values for these. I've read that if the static map and the static method that initializes it are in different files then the order of initialization isn't guaranteed but these are both in the same file.

EDIT -- To respond to jww, Dennis Chong, et.al.  As I mentioned above, the question that this question was marked as duplicate for deals with the situation where the map and the method that initializes it are defined in 2 different cpp files.  I understand that the order in that case is not guaranteed.  However the solution notes that the order of initialization is well understood when the two are in the same cpp file and should be the order in which the items are declared.  For this reason, it seemed to me that the problem was different.

Comment: Sounds the like **[static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html)**. Just avoid class type globals. Consider using a Meyers' singleton instead of the direct variable.

Comment: If `LoadAttributes()` is called by some other global constructor, then the initialization order will be indeterminate. You could start of by making the map a static variable *inside* `LoadAttributes` and see what happens.

Comment: Unrelated: Am I the only one that finds it odd `static void LoadAttributes(void);` is in the *header* file at all ? Declared as `static`, LoadAttributes is local to the current translation unit, so unless Attributes.cpp is being `#include`-ed ins some other .cpp file (which would be hideous), the declaration in the header seems pointless and unwarranted (and not the least-bit odiferous).

Comment: @WhozCraig: I just didn't see that. Happens often. I (or one) doesn't see the totally unexpected. There's an old SciAm video about that, with a man in gorilla costume waltzing through some folks concentrating on a ball game. They don't notice him.

Comment: sorry i misremembered that, it was the viewers who concentrated on counting the passes of the ball that didn't notice the (unexpected) gorilla. video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJG698U2Mvo

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
static map<string,int> AttributeTable;

void LoadAttributes(void)
{
   AttributeTable.insert(pair<string,int>("attribute1",1));
   AttributeTable.insert(pair<string,int>("attribute2",2));
   ...
}
```

To:

```
map<string,int>& GetAttributeTable()
{
    static map<string,int> AttributeTable;
    return AttributeTable;
}

void LoadAttributes(void)
{
    map<string,int>& AttributeTable = GetAttributeTable();
    AttributeTable.insert(pair<string,int>("attribute1",1));
    AttributeTable.insert(pair<string,int>("attribute2",2));
    ...
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes a specific cause that is likely, but by no means certain. It is however a good first step. If it solves the problem, fine; and if not, one possibility has been ruled out.

Comment: @Cheers - `_Right=?????, _Left=?????` gives it away. But you're right - Visual Studio is pretty accommodating and usually does not suffer this issue. Apple is least accommodating, and there's sure to be trouble with static globals (and even accessors). For Apple, see [Specify construction/destruction order of static locals in different accessors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346571/specify-construction-destruction-order-of-static-locals-in-different-accessors).

Comment: This did the trick for the void LoadAttributes(void) problem.  Now, however, anywhere I reference the map I have to call GetAttributeTable() again and it returns an empty map so, for example the following returns a 0 index even though when LoadAttributes terminated there were 339 entries:

Comment: map<string,int>::iterator indx;  map<string,int>Attributetable=GetAttributeTable();  indx=AttributeTable.find("attribute1");

Comment: The problem is solved by a variant of the solution proposed by jww that is also similar to the one in the referenced solution.  It seems that the initialization problem exists whether the map and the initialize routine are in the same or separate files.  Thanks to all for responding.